# error accessing the api with flask, either through the get or post method

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-restful

I want to access a python api with sending parameters, namely an image file. I always get the same error, 404, whatever the parameter I'm sending, images, text or even an int. how can i solve?

file app.py:

```
api.add_resource(Function4, '/faces/<string:params>')
```

file test.py:

```
class Function4(Resource):
    def post(self, params):
    
        print(params)
```